# How to print the arrays in table or dimension format?

Tags: scala

Actually this works

```
 object Matrixmul extends App {
 val a = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))
 val b = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))
 val c = Array.ofDim[Int](3, 3)
 val sum =Array.ofDim[Int](3,3)
 println(a.mkString(" "))
 val elements = for {
  row <- a
  ele <- row
   }yield ele
   for(array1 <-elements)
 println(" the 1st matrix array elements are : " + array1)
```

This prints the arrray in the format,

```
the 1st matrix array elements are : 1
the 1st matrix array elements are : 2
the 1st matrix array elements are : 3
the 1st matrix array elements are : 4
the 1st matrix array elements are : 5
the 1st matrix array elements are : 6
the 1st matrix array elements are : 7
the 1st matrix array elements are : 8
the 1st matrix array elements are : 9
```

But I need in DIMENSION format,

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: [1 2 3]
[4 5 6] 
[7 8 9]
in matrix format

Answer (score 3):

How about the following,

```
val a = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))

a.foreach(row => println(row.mkString(" ")))
```

Which will print your dimentional format,

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: YES , It works. Thanks for the solution.
EVEN this also works
println(" The 1 st ARRAY MATRIX ARE : " + "\n"+ a.deep.mkString(" \t \n"))

Answer (score 0):

Small variation on the subject

```
val a = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))

println(a.map(_.mkString(" ")).mkString("\n"))
```